# HTML Button hiding does not work properly with single click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement functionality where once the button is clicked, it hides it from the list and deselects the corresponding check-box from the hierarchy structure(TreeNode) on the left.

Rightside.component.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <ul class="selection-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of getSelections()">
      <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" *ngIf="item.selected">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

rightside.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../shared/service/data.service';
import { TreeNode } from '../../shared/dto/TreeNode';

import html from './rightside.component.html';
import css from './rightside.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'rightside-component',
  template: html,
  providers: [DataService],
  styles: [css],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class RightSideComponent implements OnInit {
  selections: string[];
  @Input() treeNode: TreeNode<string>[];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getSelections() : TreeNode<string>[] {
    if (typeof(this.treeNode) == "undefined" || (this.treeNode) === null) {
      return [];
    }
    return this.treeNode;
  }

  deselect(item: TreeNode<string>): void {
    if((item.children) !== null) {
      item.children.forEach(element => {
        this.deselect(element);
      });
    }
    item.selected = false;
  }

}
```

productline.component.html:

```
<p>Productlines</p>
<mat-input-container>
    <input #searchInput matInput placeholder="Search for Product Line">
</mat-input-container>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="PLCheck" *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
    <fortune-select
       (dataChanged)="onDataChange($event)"
       [searchTerm]="searchInput.value"
       [currentNode]="tree"
       [singleSelect]="singleSelect"
       [collapsed]="true"></fortune-select>
</div>
<div class="sendToRight">
    <rightside-component
        [treeNode]="selectedProductLine">
    </rightside-component>
</div>
</div>
```

Treenode.ts :

```
import { ValidationService } from '../service/validation.service';

export class TreeNode<T> {
  displayName:   string;
  children:      TreeNode<T>[];
  selected:      boolean;
  collapsed?:    boolean;
  indeterminate: boolean;
  selectable:    boolean;
  value:         T;

  public static getAllNodeValues<T>(tree: TreeNode<T>):T[] {
    return TreeNode.getAllCheckedNodes<T>(tree).map((nodes:TreeNode<T>) => nodes.value);
  }

  public static getTopLevelNodeValues<T>(tree: TreeNode<T>):T[] {
    return TreeNode.getTopLevelCheckedNodes<T>(tree).map((nodes:TreeNode<T>) => nodes.value);
  }

  public static getTopLevelCheckedNodes<T>(tree: TreeNode<T>):TreeNode<T>[] {
    if(tree.selected) {
      return [tree];
    } else if(tree.indeterminate) {
      return tree.children.reduce(
        (acc,child) => acc.concat(TreeNode.getTopLevelCheckedNodes(child)),[]);
    } else {
      return <TreeNode<T>[]>[];
    }
  }

  public static getAllCheckedNodes<T>(tree: TreeNode<T>):TreeNode<T>[] {
    if(tree.selected && tree.children) {
      return tree.children.reduce(
        (acc,child) => acc.concat(TreeNode.getAllCheckedNodes(child)),[tree]);
    } else if (tree.selected) {
      return [tree];
    } else if(tree.children) {
      return tree.children.reduce(
        (acc,child) => acc.concat(TreeNode.getAllCheckedNodes(child)),[]);
    } else {
      return <TreeNode<T>[]>[];
    }
  }

  public getValue(): T {
    return this.value;
  }

  public matches(searchTerm:string):boolean {
    if(this.displayName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!ValidationService.isEmptyList(this.children)) {
      return this.children.some((child) => child.matches(searchTerm));
    }
    return false;
  }

  public selectChildren(selected:boolean):void {
    if (!ValidationService.isEmptyList(this.children)) {
      this.children.map((child) => {
        child.selected = selected;
        child.indeterminate = false;
        child.selectChildren(selected);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

In the rightside.component.html, I have the buttons which basically list out the items on the right. Something similar to this plunkr I found :
 http://next.plnkr.co/edit/1Fr83XHkY0bWd9IzOwuT?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview

I have to click multiple times (on the screen somewhere else or the button itself) for it to hide. It works with a single click if I start from the bottom button and go to the top in the list. The buttons are not working with a single click for some reason.

I cant see any errors in the console and wanted to know if anything can be done to avoid this buggy behavior. I would like for the hiding to take place with single clicks for all buttons, when clicked in any order.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: instead of `item.selected = false;` you should reassign item so try `item = {...item, selected: false};`

Comment: I have updated the question and added TreeNode.ts code.                              I can see this error when I do that : Type '{ selected: false; displayName: string; children: TreeNode<string>[]; collapsed?: boolean; indete...' is not assignable to type 'TreeNode<string>'.
  Property 'getValue' is missing in type '{ selected: false; displayName: string; children: TreeNode<string>[]; collapsed?: boolean; indete...'.